# Managing assets in a TYPO3 9.5 multisite setup

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

What is the best way to separate assets in a multi site TYPO3 9.5 setup. So editors of site A do not have access to the assets of site B and vice versa. But editors with permissions to edit both sites, should have access to the assets of site A and B.

Comment: I guess you can create separate filemounts and assign them to the right BE usergroups, or is there a higher level of complexity that I am not thinking of? Can you give us more detail, like how your BE usergroups and your assets are organized?

Comment: Yeah, that's how we've been doing it so far. But there are problems when users are allowed to edit multiple pages. Which filemount do I assign to these users?

It would be nice if I could assign filemounts not to users or user groups but to sites.

Comment: what about creating  usergroups in which you assign _only_ the filemount? Something like "Permission Assets A", "Permission Assets B" (and maybe "Permission Assets All" if necessary) then you can assign them to your usergroups or your users

Comment: yeah, like riccardo said: create usergroups for access rights, filemounts etc. that way you can configure them more flexible and are not limited to only one group per site or filemount. Like [here](https://typo3worx.eu/2017/02/typo3-backend-user-management/), a bit old but still valid

Answer (score 2):

In general: try to avoid assigning anything to users directly.
Try to assign rights, acccess to BE usergroups. so you have roles which can be granted to individuals. and if someone has multiple roles he gets multiple usergroups and has the compound rights.

Be aware of some drawbacks you will not be able to avoid:

- if a user has access to multiple filemounts (because of different roles) he can use these cross over.
  In your case: if an user has access to filemount A for site A and filemount B for site B he also can use a file from A in the pages of B. Other editors with only access to site B may have problems to edit this.
- Creating new pages might hide the new pages for other users. as TYPO3 uses a similar system of rights like the unix file system you must ensure that new pages have the correct group so other members of the group can access these pages. as normaly the first group is taken it might be the group of the other site. give all pages a default group with TSconfig in the root pages of the different sites.

.

```
TCEMAIN.permissions {
    # the id if the BE usergroup who should be able to edit pages in this tree
    groupid = 13
    # now the rights for owner, group, world (1)
    user = 31
    group = 19
    everybody = 1
}
```

(1) the rights are assigned bitwise:

```
2^0 =  1 = show page (show/Copy page and content)   
2^1 =  2 = edit page (Change/Move page, eg. change page title)  
2^2 =  4 = delete page (delete page or content)  
2^3 =  8 = new pages (create new pages under this page)  
2^4 = 16 = edit content (change/ add/ delete/ move content)
```